# Sci-fi movie: futuristic city, rain, depraved youth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm 25, from France and when I was a young kid I used to watch TV every night.

Anyway, like 15 years ago I have seen a sci-fi movie. It was like in the future, an apocalyptic rainy future with black and white young people with a very dark yet bit cheap mood (it’s not *Blade Runner*).

I remember quite precisely a scene which can help: a young guy in his bed waiting for someone, and then a girl coming from the window and then brutally changing into a kind of giant insect and eating the guy.

It looked like a sad and poor evolution of an american city like Chicago where poverty, sexual tension and weirdly enough kind of alien were present

Comment: When you say "from throw the window", did you mean the girl was thrown by someone else? Also, since you watched that on TV, any ideas which channel it could have aired on? This sounds a bit like the cheap stuff M6 used to broadcast...

Comment: I mean the girl (or maybe a boy, my memory is so foggy) make his entrance by the window. Maybe by flying. Can’f remember. And absolutely it was on M6 at like 3 AM. Haha amazing how do you know that. Are you french too ?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)